# Restrict Access to Web Server for Specific Devices

Tags: java, android, ios, tomcat, authentication

I have a web application running on Apache Tomcat and this Web Application runs on a server to which my Frontend connects. The Frontend's could be a Browser or and App that runs on Android or iOS.

I would now like to allow access to my Tomcat Web App only to specific devices that I device. Restricting access using IP address / MAC address might be the dumbest solution that I could think of, but that is doomed to fail given the diversity of the routers that could be inbetween the device and my Web App. So how do I potentially decide access to my Web App only to some specific devices?

I can see that Google already does this! I mean if I log in to my Google E-Mail account from a completely new device, it would prevent me from doing so and asks me for an authentication token from one of my trusted devices. Is there any AI or some funky Machine Learning happening behind the scenes at Google that actually checks for registered devices?

I would like to do the same to my Web Application running on Tomcat. So how do I do this? Any suggestions?

Comment: Set a Cookie for permitted devices & test for its existence, this is what google does.

Comment: What if I disable the cookies completely? I have moved away from using Cookies. I use a JWT Token for session management!